# How to get 1 initContainer when parallelism is set > 1

Tags: kubernetes

I have a job in Kubernetes as defined below (with some omissions for brevity). Parallelism and N completions are set. I want 1 init container to delay the start of the parallel containers. When I run it as-is I get an init container per each completion it appears.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-job
spec:
  parallelism: 10
  completions: 10
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    spec:

      # I want 1 of these to run first
      initContainers:
      - name: init-container
        image: my/container:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["init_script.sh"]

      # I want 10 of these to run in parallel once init_script.sh exits
      containers:
      - name: container
        image: my/container:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["run_job.sh"]

      restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes Jobs are very basic and don't provide any advanced scheduling mechanism with scheduling dependencies. For example, the ability to start a job after another job has finished. My advice is to use a more advanced scheduling tool on top of Kubernetes. There are few in open source that you can use. For example.

- [Volcano](https://volcano.sh/) - For example you can use the [`TaskCompleted`](https://volcano.sh/docs/jobs/#error-handling) event.
- [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) - You can schedule pods directly from the tools and build your [DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph).](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/06/28/airflow-on-kubernetes-part-1-a-different-kind-of-operator/)
- Etc.

Two other alternatives:

- You can even create your own [custom scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers).
- You can build your own [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) that kicks off your regular jobs based on status.

✌️